# Advice for increasing endurance

Tags: training

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve my stamina?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-can-i-improve-my-stamina)

I would like to improve my endurance while bicycling.
I'm especially interested in increasing my endurance while going up a slope (since right now I get tired very easily while doing this and have to stop to take a rest quite often).

What advice would you give me on this?
Do you know any good training program that you would recommend?

Comment: Do whatever it is that seems to demonstrate your lack of endurance, only do it a little longer and more aggressively each time (with appropriate rest intervals between).

Answer (score 4):

Adding a hill repeats workout to your training routine is the best way to increase your climbing endurance. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBrWyCVOwOY) on one way to do hill repeats.

Find a hill with a good grade in your area.
Basically, you warm up and get yourself loose and ready for an intense workout, then ride up the hill making sure to time your effort then use the same amount of time to go back down the hill and recover then repeat.

Start off with a few reps and build up.

Answer (score 2):

I've found going up slight-to-moderate but LONG slopes (more than one mile) makes me feel a lot easier when going up moderate-to-steep hills of any length.

The fact is that one of the principles of exercise training is that if you want to get better in some specific activity, you should perform that activity, in a level enough to promote enhancement of capacity over time.

Hope this helps!